# Convert loop and if statemnt to a list comprehension

Tags: python, list

Is it possible to convert the following to a python list comprehension:

```
values = [a,b,c,d,...]

converted_values = []
for item in values:
    if type(item) == datetime.date:
        converted_values.append(item)
    else:
        converted_values.append(item.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: if you have to do type checking like that, your design is probably already broken...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [Conditional Expressions](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) to make this work.

```
converted_values = [item if type(item) == datetime.data
                    else item.decode('utf-8')
                    for item in values]
```

Python conditionals are fairly readable. Here's some examples to show how they work:

```
print("yes" if True else "no") # prints "yes"
print("yes" if False else "no") # prints "no"
```

Answer (score 5):

```
converted_values = [item if type(item) == datetime.date else item.decode('utf-8')
                       for item in values]
```

I assume you meant `utf-8`.

Also, the Python docs recommend using `isinstance(item, datetime.date)` rather than `type(item) == datetime.date`.